# Extending a serialized django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to extend a serialized django model so the json/xml output includes a custom tag (anywhere in the body is fine).

Currently I am doing something like this to serialize the model.

```
data = serializers.serialize('xml', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
```

But how to extend it with say (or similar):

```
<field type="CharField" name="CustomString">Hello World</field>
```

So ultimately this is what I'd like to do:

```
custom_field = [{'notes':'Hello World'}]
data = serializers.serialize('xml', SomeModel.objects.all()+custom_field, fields=('name','size','notes'))
```

Is this possible? Let me know if I need to explain it more. Thanks!

Comment: ['<%s type="%s" name="%s">Hello World</%s>' % (each.tagName, each.type, each.name, each.tagName) for each in data] is that what you want?

Comment: Patrick, see above. I extended the question above re what I seeking.

Comment: the editing didn't help much. Still I can't see what you're trying to do.

Comment: i'll make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
custom_field = [{'notes':'Hello World'}]
my_objects = SomeModel.objects.all()
exec (('each.%s = %s' % key, value)¨for key, value in custom_field.items()) for each in my_objects
data = serializers.serialize('xml', my_objects, 
    fields=('name','size','notes'))
```

might work.